# Cannot resolve method "compareTo(Friend)"

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist, data-structures, comparable

I'm creating a FriendList which extends ArrayList and is populated with a Friend object.  However when I try accessing methods normally available to Friend, the compiler says it cannot resolve the method - in this case compareTo(Friend).

FriendList class:

```
public class FriendList<Friend> extends ArrayList<Friend> {

    private boolean isAdded;

    public FriendList() {
        isAdded = false;
    }

    public void alphabetAdd(Friend friend) {
        if (this.isEmpty()) {
            add(friend);
            return;
        }

        int index = 0;

        // add friends alphabetically
        while (!isAdded) {
            Friend f = this.get(index+1);
            if (f.compareTo(friend) < 0) {
                index++;
            } else {
                this.add(index, friend);
                isAdded = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Friend class:

```
public class Friend implements Comparable<Friend> {

// constructors and other methods work fine - just need to see compareTo

//    @Override
    public int compareTo(@NonNull Friend o) {

        String name1 = getUserFirstName() + getUserLastName();
        Friend f;

        if (o instanceof Friend) {
            f = (Friend) o;

            String name2 = f.getUserFirstName() + f.getUserLastName();

            if (name1.compareTo(name2) < 0)
                return -1;
            else if (name1.compareTo(name2) > 0)
                return 1;

        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `Friend f = this.get(index+1);` actually returning anything?

Comment: `this.get(index+1)` returns a Friend from FriendList which.  I just stored it to a variable

Comment: Do you really need this inheritance hierarchy ?

Comment: It should work - either you have multiple `Friend` classes in different packages, and you're importing the wrong one into `FriendList` - or the error is saying something (possibly subtly) different. Include the *exact* error message (copy/paste) in your question and add in which packages your classes are and how you are importing them.

Comment: the exact error message is what i have in the title.  I might try specifying the package directory for Friend

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is in `FriendList<Friend>`. This is treated as a declaration of generic class like `FriendList<T>` and `Friend` becomes not an actual type but an alias that is why only methods declared in `Object` are available.
Change declaration of your class to 
`public class FriendList extends ArrayList<Friend>`

Comment: Thanks I knew it was something simple like that.